# Place logo + change its opacity and scale + add text at random position

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 3 complex filters and can't figure how do i make it in one command to work:

1. Random text position
   `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf drawtext=\"fontsize=40:fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:fontcolor={color}:text='{watermarkText}':x=if(eq(mod(n\\,20)\\,0)\\,rand(0\\,(w-text_w))\\,x):y=if(eq(mod(n\\,20)\\,0)\\,rand(0\\,(h-text_h))\\,y)\" -c:a copy {outputFile}`
2. Logo opacity
   `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i pog.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.1*alpha(X,Y)'[zork]; [0:v][zork]overlay" {outputFile}`
3. Logo scaling
   `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i pog.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w='iw*10/100':h='ow/mdar'[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=10:10" video1.mp4`

Is it even possible to make it as one working command?